# Convert time-string into individual hex bytes

Tags: python, datetime, hex, byte

```
dt = datetime.datetime.now()
dt = dt.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
t = dt.decode("hex")
print list(t)
```

is returning `[' ', '\x15', '\x12', ')', '\x10', ')', '6']`. But it is not converted to hex. Though I want to have eg. year-`2015` must be converted to `\x07\xdf` and accordingly convert `month, date, hour, minute, second` into their respective `hex`. Anyone who could help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print:

```
dt = dt.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
print list(dt)
```

You'll get:

> ['2', '0', '1', '5', '1', '2', '2', '9', '0', '8', '3', '7', '3', '2']

If you convert to Hex:

```
t = dt.decode("hex")
print list(t)
```

You'll get:

> [' ', '\x15', '\x12', ')', '\x08', 'B', '\x07']

A hybrid solution like [Jorge Torres](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4413370/jorge-torres) said would be something like:

```
mystr=""
mystr+=hex(dt.year)
mystr+=hex(dt.month)
mystr+=hex(dt.day)
mystr+=hex(dt.hour)
mystr+=hex(dt.minute)
mystr+=hex(dt.second)
print mystr
```

The result would be what you want:

> 0x7df0xc0x1d0x80x2f0x6

If you're worried with performance issues here's an example of 1M iteration in my machine (a core2duo) I've removed the print :

```
@timeit
def tst_1():
    for i in range(1000000):
        dt = datetime.datetime.now()
        mystr=""
        mystr+=hex(dt.year)
        mystr+=hex(dt.month)
        mystr+=hex(dt.day)
        mystr+=hex(dt.hour)
        mystr+=hex(dt.minute)
        mystr+=hex(dt.second)
        #print mystr
    
@timeit 
def tst_2():
    for i in range(1000000):
        dt = datetime.datetime.now()
        dt = dt.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
        t = dt.decode("hex")
        #print list(t)
```

Result:

> func:'tst_1' args:[(), {}] took: 3.6850 sec
>
> func:'tst_2' args:[(), {}] took: 9.9950 sec

So decoding Hex from string actually took 2.7 times more time.

Comment: Yes. That is right but I want to have `\x07` and `\xdf` byte-wise read.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for:

```
import datetime;
dt = datetime.datetime.now()
print hex(dt.year)
print hex(dt.month)
print hex(dt.day)
print hex(dt.hour)
print hex(dt.minute)
print hex(dt.second)
```

This will give you the hex numbers you are looking for. If you want them in a list, you can append each of them to an empty list.

Comment: That would work But, my concern is won't it affect the values while executing for million times. Because python is executing statement one by one so it might not be feasible.

Comment: Interesting. Can you specify how often you're trying to loop? What would be the output that you expect? Probably there's a solution

Comment: I am currently have hundreds of nodes which are sending me data. I want to know time at packets reached at me. There is no looping but suppose when all nodes are transmitting at instance. For that case I may not get expected result.

Comment: I see. It depends on how you use this code. In the example above 'dt' will contain the time at which datetime.datetime.now() is called. When you use '.year', '.second', etc, you are using a copy of the time that was saved in 'dt', so 'dt' does not get modified/updated while the hex conversion takes place. If you make this code run in a function, and such function runs every time that the packed arrives, as long as you create 'dt' at the top of the function, the time saved in 'dt' will be the closest to the time of arrival of that packet.